# How do I play non-Steam games on Steam?

Tags: steam

My aunt handed me Might and Magic 6 and I installed the game with the disks and she told me that you can open it with Steam but she couldn't remember how.

How do I open it with Steam? Is it even possible?

Comment: You'd need a code from it to activate it on steam

Answer (score 6):

You can get your game to run with Steam by going to the Games tab at the top of the screen. Once you open that tab select Add Non-Steam game to my Library. It should open up a window that lets you select a executable file you want to add to Steam. Select your exe that you want to add to your library and confirm. Then when you launch the game through Steam you are able to open up the Steam overlay like you would a normal Steam game.